# Можно ли передать переменную в querySelectorAll() и classList.add()?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Допустим, есть переменная, в которую записывается имя класса: `let class1 = 'lalala'`

Есть ли какой-то способ присвоить новый класс элементу, используя переменную `class1`?

Пришло в голову сделать так: `elem.classList.add(class1)`, однако это не сработало. Аналогичная ситуация с querySelectorAll. Если передать переменную `class1ForQuery = '.lalala'` в querySelectorAll, то результат также никакой.

Comment: Где-то у вас в другом месте ошибка. В случае с querySelectorAll, может быть, нет на странице элементов с необходимым классом, или еще что-нибудь банальное в этом роде. Строки в функции через переменные передаются в js без проблем :)

Comment: _Пришло в голову сделать так: elem.classList.add(class1), однако это не сработало._ - почему ты думаешь, что это не сработало?

Comment: При добавлении этого класса элементам с querySelectorAll, ты запускаешь цикл forEach???

Comment: Голос за переоткрытие, потому что указанная причина закрытия вопроса неадекватна его содержимому (слово "допустим" перед описанием примера, явно указывает на общий характер описания - это определенно не запрос помощи в отладке). Более того, в вопросе присутствует осмысленное вопросительное предложение, на которое можно дать точный ответ.

Comment: @yar85, ну так вы же уже дали ответ. зачем переоткрывать вопрос?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, цель переоткрытия вопроса - дать ему еще один шанс быть не прибранным Духом. Вопрос хоть и не идеален, но он ищется по тексту, и вполне может оказаться полезным (имхо). А если все же закрывать его, то по _реальной_ причине - проявляя должное отношение. Пардон, а что меняет факт _«ну так вы же уже дали ответ.»_, как это связано с переоткрытием?

Comment: @yar85, открыт/закрыт вопрос — влияет (в данном случае) только на возможность/невозможность добавить ещё ответ(ы). так зачем открывать?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, спасибо за пояснение взаимосвязи с ответом. О цели переоткрытия, я уже написал ранее - что именно в ней осталось непонятным, какими подробностями дополнить?

Answer (score 1):

Ваш ход мыслей абсолютно правильный, для этого можно воспользоваться методом [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), в примере ниже видно что все присвоения/изменения работают корректно:

```js
const element = document.querySelector("#root")
let class1 = "lalala"
element.classList.add(class1)
console.log(element.classList.value)

class1 = "land"
element.classList.add(class1)
console.log(element.classList.value)
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Другое дело если вы хотите что бы классы присваивались элементу автоматически, сразу после того как вы изменили переменную, тогда Вам следует реализовать что то что будет отслеживать изменение переменной `class1` и вызывать метод `classList`.

Comment: А ты пробовал запускать свой код? `const element = document.querySelectorAll("#root")
let class1 = "lalala"
element.classList.add(class1)`

Comment: @Grundy Что конкретно Вас не устроило в приведенном выше коде? Если Вы увидели опечатку `querySelectorAll` вместо `querySelector` то стоило так и написать в комментарии. Добавляйте конкретики в Ваши коментарии что бы они превращались в конструктивную критику. Если это относиться не к `querySelector` то я буду рад услышать вашу позицию

Comment: Из контекста непонятно что это была опечатка, так как в вопросе тоже речь шла про querySelectorAll.

Answer (score -1):

Свойство `classList` возвращает живую коллекцию. То есть, значение этого свойства указывает на объект, который автоматически обновляется при изменении набора классов элемента.

```js
const elem = document.querySelector('.test')
      elemClassList = elem.classList;

document.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if (target.matches('button.add')) {
    const newClass = Array.from({ length: 5 },
      () => String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * 26) + 97)
    ).join('');
    elemClassList.add(newClass);
    console.log(`Добавлен класс "${newClass}":\n${elem.outerHTML}`);
  } else if (target.matches('button.find')) {
    const selector = ['', ...elemClassList.values()].join('.'),
          searchResult = document.querySelector(selector);
    console.log(`Выбор из документа по селектору "${selector}":\n${searchResult && searchResult.outerHTML}`);
  }
});
```

```html
<button class="add">Добавить элементу случайный класс</button>
<button class="find">Найти элемент по селектору всех его классов</button>
<p class="test"></p>
```